# Adding JLabel dynamically in a pattern but last one is not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to creating 40 dynamical **JLabels** in a **pattern**, which is working quite good but the last **JLabel** is not placing according to the pattern. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong ?

Here what I have done so far:

```
public class Booking2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jf.setSize(700, 400);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        int c1 = 40;
        int count = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, x;
        JLabel[] jl = new JLabel[c1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= c1 - 1; i++) {
            jl[i] = new JLabel();

            if (i <= 9) {
                x = 25 * count;
                jl[i].setBounds(x, 50, 20, 30);
                count++;
            }
            if (i >= 10 && i <= 19) {
                x = 25 * count2;
                jl[i].setBounds(x, 80, 20, 20);
                count2++;
            }
            if (i >= 20 && i <= 29) {
                x = 25 * count3;
                jl[i].setBounds(x, 110, 20, 20);
                count3++;
            }
            if (i >= 30 && i <= 39) {
                x = 25 * count4;
                jl[i].setBounds(x, 130, 20, 20);
                count4++;
            }
            // jl[i].setIcon(new
            // ImageIcon(Booking2.class.getResource("booked.png")));
            jl[i].setText("O");
            jf.add(jl[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the pattern behind the layout?  Please trim screenshots.  See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)

Comment: why don't you use a grid layout for this?

Comment: better question than previous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using absolute positioning / null layout but you haven't set layout to null .default layout of jframe is Border layout.

add this line

```
jf.setLayout(null);
```

and after you add all components call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` method of jframe.

example

```
public class Booking2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jf.setLayout(null); // this is important 

        jf.setSize(700, 400);

        int c1 = 40;
        int count = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, x;
        JLabel[] jl = new JLabel[c1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= c1 - 1; i++) {
            jl[i] = new JLabel();

            if (i <= 9) {
                x = 25 * count;
                jl[i].setBounds(x, 50, 20, 20);
                count++;
            }
            if (i >= 10 && i <= 19) {
                x = 25 * count2;
                jl[i].setBounds(x, 80, 20, 20);
                count2++;
            }
            if (i >= 20 && i <= 29) {
                x = 25 * count3;
                jl[i].setBounds(x, 110, 20, 20);
                count3++;
            }
            if (i >= 30 && i <= 39) {
                x = 25 * count4;
                jl[i].setBounds(x, 130, 20, 20);
                count4++;
            }
            //jl[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(Booking2.class.getResource("booked.png")));
            jl[i].setText("O");
            jf.add(jl[i]);
        }
         jf.revalidate();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

output

[image]

**Note**

1) you should avoid null layout .use a layout GRID layout seems good for your case .and also if this is a kind of a game /animation you should look at these example https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html. you can use `paintComponent()` method to draw this grid in a jpanel which is efficient and you can draw any kind of pattern .think if you make a big grid,for instance 100*100 using jlables it's not good

2) it's better to add components to jpanel instead of add directly to jframe .you can use `setContentPane()` method for that

Answer (score 4):

It would be much better to use layout, for example `GridLayout`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Booking2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,10));
        jf.setSize(700, 400);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        int c1=40;
        JLabel[] jl = new JLabel[c1];

        for(int i=c1-1; i>=0; i--){
            jl[i]=new JLabel();
            jl[i].setText("O");
            jf.add(jl[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It is more elegant way. But, if you are determined to use `setBound()` you should set `JFrame` (or other container with your `JLabels`) layout to null:

```
jf.setLayout(null);
```

This will allow for absolute positioning inside container. It seems that default `JFrames` `BorderLoyout` distorted your `setBounds()` settings.

**However it is generally not recomended to use null layout, and it is considered a bad programming practice. It is better idea to use LayoutMenagers!**

Comment: `jf.setVisible(true); .. jf.setSize(700, 400);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` would better be `jf.pack();
        jf.setLocationRelativeByPlatform(true); jf.setVisible(true);`

Comment: How to set the inner padding and spacings in a grid layout ? @m.cekiera

Comment: @Pappu take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)